# Is my formula wrong or is there any line of codes that made it wrong?

Tags: java, user-interface, event-handling

This is my full source code.

Seems like I could not get the output. I successfully can get the user interface but when I entered any number to get the surface area of a sphere and the volume, I could not get the exact answer. I don't know if I messed up the formula or is there something wrong with my event handling codes.

[image]

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Sphere extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    private JLabel radius, result;
    private JTextField tfRadius, tfResult;
    private JButton btnArea, btnVol; 
    private JPanel p1, p2;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Sphere S = new Sphere();
        S.setSize(300, 150);
        S.setVisible(true);
        S.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);        
    }

    public Sphere() {
        setTitle("Sphere");
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        radius = new JLabel("Radius");
        result = new JLabel("Result");
        tfRadius = new JTextField(10);
        tfResult = new JTextField(10);
        tfResult.setEditable(false);
        btnArea = new JButton("Surface Area");
        btnVol = new JButton("Volume");

        p1 = new JPanel();
        p1.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2, 2, 2));
        p1.add(radius);
        p1.add(tfRadius);
        p1.add(result);
        p1.add(tfResult);

        p2 = new JPanel();
        p2.add(btnArea); 
        p2.add(btnVol);

        add(p1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(p2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);   

        btnArea.addActionListener(this);
        btnVol.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.0000");
        double result = 0;
        //double pi = 3.142; before I edited.
        double radius = Double.parseDouble(tfRadius.getText());

        //action from the respective button
        if(e.getSource() == btnArea) {
            result = 4 * (Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 2)); //edited from pi to Math.pi
        } else if (e.getSource() == btnVol) {
            result = 4.0/3.0 * (Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 3)); //edited from 1.333 to 4.0/3.0
        }

        tfResult.setText(String.valueOf(df.format(result)));            
    }
}
```

Comment: "`double pi`" how about using `Math.PI`? Similarly: "`1.333`" would be more easily written as `4.0/3.0`.

Comment: For more precise answers you also could consider a `BigDecimal` type. It won't help with value of `PI`, but can help with not losing precision in intermediate steps of computations.

Comment: @AndyTurner thanks! I've changed the following codes to Math.PI and 4.0/3.0 and I got the exact value for volume but I couldn't get the answer for the surface area.

Comment: For surface area also you need to change to Math.PI. Did you do that?

Comment: @PrasadKarunagoda yes, I did change it to Math.PI

Comment: With `Math.PI` change I got the correct value for surface area also.